# Removing page title on the wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

[image]

This is a wordpress page i m developing. Can anyone tell me how to remove that HOME right beyond the menu in the page and also one extra HOME.

Answer (score 0):

For the Menu: admin > Appearance > Menu

For the page title: You will have to look into page.php file in the WP theme folder and remove/comment the function `the_title()`